# Unable to load data to jquery pagination

Tags: jquery, pagination

Am trying to add pagination tryed in many was still no luck

Able to add pagination numbers still i need next and previous buttons also

and unable to appand data based on pagenumber

```
var celivalue = 66;
var PerPageCount = 25;
    for (i = 2; i < celivalue; i++) { 

        if(celivalue>1) {

        searchresultDiv   = '<div class="panel panel-default searchhotel_box" data-id = '+i+' >'+
                            '<div class="panel-body" data-hotel-name='+branchName+' data-latitude='+lat+' data-longitude='+lang+' data-landmark='+landmark+'data-locationName='+branchlocation+' data-location='+cityId+' data-price='+productPrice+'><input type="hidden" value=\''+mealsVoucherContent+'\' id="mealsVoucherContent'+searchIndex+'">'+imgdisc+
                            '<div class="meal-details col-lg-9">';
        //console.log(searchresultDiv);
        }
        }
        tjq("#meal-searchlist").append(searchresultDiv);


        searchIndex = parseInt(searchIndex)+parseInt(1);
        tjq("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({social_tools:false,deeplinking:false});
        //tjq("a[rel^='prettyPhotoTemp']").prettyPhoto({social_tools:false,deeplinking:false});

    });

     // to display buttons
     var pageulcount = '';
            for (i = 2; i < celivalue; i++) { 
                tjq(".pagination").append('<li class="page-item pgphoto active"  id="initialPhotoGalleryLoad'+i+'" data-id='+i+'><a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0)">'+i+'</a></li>');

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need in here is the datatable. It's from jquery. It's as simple as

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').dataTable();
});
</script>
```

[image]

[Reference](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/823490/Bootstrap-Table-With-Sorting-Searching-and-Paging)